# is this possible in c# ? only one class access base class method and second class can not access the same base class method

Tags: c#

A is base class

B is derived from A and also C is derived from A

I want only B can access the method of A , C an not access of that same method of A.

```
class A {

    protected void Foo() {
    }
}

class B : A {

    void Bar() {
        this.Foo(); // OK
    }
}

class C : A {
    void Baz() {
        this.Foo(); // I don't want to permit this
    }
}
```

HOW IT POSSIBLE IN c#

Comment: C being an (deriving from) A and C not behaving like an A is an OO-nonsense

Comment: Are A and B in the same assembly and C on another one ?

Comment: Can you enlighten us with the use case where this make sense?

Comment: IT NOT POSSIBLE THAT HOW

Comment: @EdPlunkett it is possible if A and B are in same assembly and C in another one.

Comment: @CodeNotFound ohhhh internal you mean? Cool. Orrible though.

Answer (score 2):

I think this look like a problem for `Interface segregation principle`:

> Clients should not be forced to depend upon interfaces that they don't
>   use.

But in your case this can be rephrased for the class inheritance.

Create pure base class (without a method you want to hide from class `C`)

```
public class Base
{
    protected void SomeDummyMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

Then create your `A` class which inherit from `Base` and add a method you what to share for class `B`

```
public class A : Base
{
    protected void YourFooMethod()
    {

    }
}
```

Create `B` class which inherit from `A` and will have access to all functionality including `YourFooMethod`

```
public class B : A
{
    public void Bar() 
    {
        this.YourFooMethod();
    }
}
```

And finally your `C` class which have all base functionality except `YourFooMethod` method

```
public class C : Base
{
    public void Bar() 
    {
        this.YourFooMethod(); //Compile error: YourFooMethod is not a member of...
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you could write code in class A that checks the calling class name against a white list or a black list and throws an exception in the cases you want to disallow, but I would not recommend doing this. That would be very difficult to maintain, and class A should not need to know about every class that extends it.

What you are trying to do is really honestly a bad idea.

Comment: Have you heared about `L` in `SOLID`?

Comment: _"checks the calling class name against a white list"_ - please don't suggest such antipatterns. But alright, you've got enough "don't do this" in your answer.

Comment: @HamletHakobyan yes, I have. Hence the multiple places where I said that this is a bad idea. He asked if it could be done. Technically, it can. Which I think he deserves to be told. It just happens to be a really, really bad idea

Answer (score 0):

C# (and .NET in general) has the access modifiers:

- `public` - Anyone can access
- `private` - Only the containing scope/type can access
- `protected` - Only the containing type and its derived types can access
- `internal` - Only types defined in the same Assembly (or `InternalsVisibleTo` Assemblies) can access
- `protected internal` - The set-union of `protected` and `internal` can access.

You're asking for something in-between `private` and `protected`, where you can manually restrict access to named types.

This is not currently possible to enforce, at least at compile-time, in .NET - though if types `A` and `B` exist in the same assembly and `C` exists in a different assembly then `internal` would work.

At runtime you could enforce this with code-access-security, or more simply: using reflection to get the calling-class's name (`this.GetType()`), or use a password:

or more simpler: a password requirement:

```
class A {
    private Boolean isAllowedAccess;

    protected A(String password) {
        this.isAllowedAccess = password == "12345abc";
    }

    protected void Foo() {
        if( !this.isAllowedAccess ) throw new InvalidOperationException();
    }
}

class B : A {

    public B() : base("12345abc") {
    }

    void Bar() {
        this.Foo(); // OK
    }
}

class C : A {

    public C() : base(null) {
    }

    void Baz() {
        this.Foo(); // I don't want to permit this
    }
}
```

Comment: The solution with `protected internal` I think is the cleanest way if A and B are in the same assembly while C is in another one.

Comment: @CodeNotFound I think you mean `internal` because C would still have access to `Foo` if `C : A` if it were `protected internal`. `protected internal` does not mean "only derived types in the same assembly`, it means "derived types AND same-assembly types".

Comment: Don't see the point of keeping password for this purpose. Why not checking the type at runtime: `isAllowedAccess = this.GetType() != typeof(A)`

Comment: @YosiDahari I suggested using a password if you want to allow other, design-time unknown types, in future without changing the program.

Comment: Another this is that you make A "decide" that it's not allowed by `base(null)`. Meaning, there should be no action that A can do that will enable access to `Foo`